# Google Apps Script: Open the sheet on 'Todays' Date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got an annual calendar split by week, and a whole bunch of content cells in between each week. Essentially, B2:F2 has Jan 1 to Jan 5, and then B15:F15 has Jan 9 to Jan 15, for example.

I'm trying to get this sheet to open on the cell containing Todays date, but the below script allows me to search for 'Today' in just one column (D:D). I'm not able to get it to work on the entire sheet.

So far I have:

```
function onOpen() {
 var menu = [{name: "Jump to today's date", functionName: "jumpToDate"}];
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Custom", menu);
 jumpToDate();
}

function jumpToDate() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("D:D");
 var values = range.getValues();  

 var day = 24*3600*1000;  
 var today = parseInt((new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))/day);  
 var ssdate; 
 for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
   try {
     ssdate = values[i][0].getTime()/day;
   }

   catch(e) {
   }
   if (ssdate && Math.floor(ssdate) == today) {
     sheet.setActiveRange(range.offset(i,0,1,1));
     break;
   }    
 }
  Logger.log(ssdate);
}
```

This seems to only work on column D, but every time I try to expand the range in this line: It doesn't work.

```
  var range = sheet.getRange("Invoice!B2:F500");
```

Does anyone know how I could make this work?

NOte: I did not write this script, I got it off [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/78927/how-to-make-google-sheets-jump-to-todays-row-when-opened) thread :)

Thank you!

Edit:

We only go off a 5 day week (Monday to Friday)

Here's what the sheet looks like:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JQxXy-ErVKATh5cUCD7u6QLQkaDyXfhhGuMKs_xgbh4/edit?usp=sharing

And here's an image:
[spreadhseetexample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T00vT.png)

Comment: Please provide an image of your spreadsheet.

Comment: Please explain how  how 7 days fit into 5 cells for `B15:F15`

Comment: Where are Jan 6,7 and 8?

Comment: Hi @Cooper! Thanks for helping out. I've put this link in for you, tell me if it makes sense? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JQxXy-ErVKATh5cUCD7u6QLQkaDyXfhhGuMKs_xgbh4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I  sorry but I no longer following links to spreadsheets from this site.   An image would be great though.

Comment: @Cooper Image in there now!

Answer (score 0):

The code you're using only works for a single column range  and you want to use a multiple column range. I recommend you to implement a solution using [TestFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#createtextfinderfindtext) class. Here's an example for your case:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];

// Creates  a text finder.
var textFinder = sheet.createTextFinder(today);

// Returns the first occurrence cell of 'today' in the sheet.
var firstOccurrenceRange = textFinder.findNext();

// Sets the active range
sheet.setActiveRange(firstOccurrenceRange)
```

Comment: Thank you so much but my scripting skills aren't up there yet. i tried to replace the 'today' string with the function from my original code and it doesn't work. Here's what I've done, can you tell me what isn't ok?

Comment: What I've done after your feedback:

function onOpen() {
 var menu = [{name: "1 Jump to today's date", functionName: "jumpTo2Date"}];
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Custom", menu);
 jumpTo2Date();
}

function jumpTo2Date() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];

 var day = 24*3600*1000;  
 var today = parseInt((new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))/day);  
 var textFinder = sheet.createTextFinder(today);
var firstOccurrenceRange = textFinder.findNext();
     sheet.setActiveRange(firstOccurrenceRange);
   }

Comment: and here's my error: Exception: Invalid argument in line 15

sheet.setActiveRange(firstOccurrenceRange);

Comment: @KennethLobo I see that you proposed an edit for this answer. Editing an answer as a way to dialog with the person who wrote that answer is not a good way to operate. If the comments are not sufficient for posting code, try [moving the conversation to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/), but keep in mind that the person who posted the answer my not have time to keep helping you. Don't forget to upvote all useful answers and accept the one that addresses your question

Comment: @KennethLobo if an answer helped but you run into more problems, post a new question. And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thank you @Codebling!!

Answer (score 0):

**Jumping to a date**

`var dt` is today's date so if you want to test this on your current calendar then use the line that I commented out.  The parameters are fullyear, month, day
where month is 0-11 and day is 1 - 31.  It's all in the JavaScript reference for Date object.

Be careful with the date formatting because they have to be exact matches and remember to use getDisplayValues() not getValues() for the comparison.

You probably will need to create an installable onOpen trigger and don't use the name onOpen() otherwise you will get more than one trigger which may cause problems.  I tested this code in legacy ES5 also called Rhino

```
function jumpToDate() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sc=2;
  var sr=2
  var dt=new Date();
  //var dt= new Date(2020,0,28);//used this for testing
  var da=dt.getDay();
  var ds=Utilities.formatDate(dt,Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "EEEEEEE, MMMMMMM dd, yyyy");
  var rg=sh.getRange(sr,sc+da-1,sh.getLastRow()-sr+1,1);
  var vs=rg.getDisplayValues();  
  var today=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate());
  for(var i=0;i<vs.length;i++) {
    if(ds==vs[i][0]) {
      sh.getRange(i+sr,sc+da-1).activate();  
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

[Javascript  Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Amazing! Thank you, let me try this next week and come back to you :)

Comment: IT WORKS! Thank you so much!!